# AWS RDS pg_transport failed to download file data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

When running the following command

```
SELECT transport.import_from_server(%s,5432,'My RDS ADMIN USER',%s,%s,%s,true);
```

I get the following response from the command:

```
AWS RDS pg_transport failed to download file data
```

Both RDS are in the same region, same vpc, both have security groups allowing the connection between them, SG only has inbound for 5432

Unable to find documentation or any further info on possible failure.

Steps followed were: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrating-databases-using-rds-postgresql-transportable-databases/

With existing RDS instances, both are running Postgresql 11.5 and custom data instead of the one from the tutorial.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please recheck if your source instance Security group allows connection from destination instance?
Recheck all the parameters that you have set in the source and destination param groups.

Comment: Hi, thks for the answer, but yes, I've checked the SG for the ingress for source, and was accepting from the target CIDR block.
Parameters were set as well, documentation is still lacking but the issue was created at https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-rds-user-guide/issues/95

Answer (score 0):

Had this before, it seems to be a bug within pg_transport.

Advice from AWS was to use a larger instance class on both the source and target instances. It seems to be stable using db.m5.4xlarge